Can there be structures made from neutrinos that can have angular momentum?
Would it be possible to eventually have structures made from neutrinos somewhere in the universe, as it is indicated in this question (Are neutrino stars theoretically possible?), like halos of neutrino gas surrounding the center of galaxies?
And if it would be possible, could they have high amounts of angular momentum?

I feel like the linked question still answers the first part of your question. That's it's still a plausible thing that could occur.

Not an expert in neutrinos, but aren't right-hander neutrinos a candidate for dark matter? (Which does form halos and stuff)

@Triatticus and about the second question, could these structures have high amounts of angular momentum? Is it physically possible?

@NíckolasAlves yes, but right-handed neutrinos are hypotehtical. Could these structures be formed by the neutrinos we know for certain that do exist?

I mean any structure will probably have angular momentum, I'm not sure what you distinguish as high angular momentum, it must stay bound so there is going to be some form of upper limit on it.

@Triatticus I mean, structures like black holes, neutron stars or white dwarfs can have high spin rates and therefore high angular momentum. I was wondering whether it could be possible also for structures made from neutrinos... Also, would these structures emit gravitational waves causing them to collapse into a central point in the galaxy in the future?

Anything that has a nonzero rate of change of the gravitational quadrupole moment emits gravitational radiation. It would basically depend on how spherical your distribution was.

So, in the case that the structures made from neutrinos would emit gravitational waves, they will end in collapsed structures, like "stars" mentioned in the stack exchange question that I linked in the OP? And even if they collapse, the angular momentum would be conserved right? @Triatticus

(Just asking to confirm) @Triatticus
